# Linq to select objects where children have no associated children

Tags: c#, linq

Have the following hierarchy:

AvailabilityCounts can have many MemberCounts
Each MemberCount can have one Booking

I need a linq statement that will select all AvailabilityCounts which have at least one child MemberCount for which there is no associated Booking.

I've got this far:

```
var test = rep.AvailabilityCounts_Get()
          .Where(a => a.MemberCounts
                .Where(m => m.Bookings.Any())
          .Count() > 0);
```

This works when the AvailabilityCount has multiple MemberCounts, but ends up with opposite results when there's only one MemberCount.

Apologies for using other people's brains to do my work, but struggling to see the logic in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
var test = rep.AvailabilityCounts_Get().Where(a => a.MemberCounts
                                                    .Any(m => !m.Bookings.Any()));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say an Any() and a not Any() should do what you want.

```
rep.AvailabilityCounts_Get.Where(m => m.MemberCounts.Any(x => !x.Bookings.Any());
```